# Calling a Objective-C method using Swift 3

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I'm going crazy here.

I'm trying to call a Objective-c method in Swift following some answers here on StackOverflow and other sites.
But i'm getting some errors initializing the method...

```
#error : Cannot convert value of type '()' to specified type 'getEvents'
```

Is it because of Swift 3? what am i doing wrong here?

Here is my full code:

getEvents.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface getEvents : NSString

+(NSString *) objGetEvents:(NSString *)latitude andLon:(NSString *)longitude andRadius:(NSString *)radius andMeasure:(NSString *)measure;

@end
```

getEvents.m

```
#import "getEvents.h"

@implementation getEvents

+(NSString *) objGetEvents:(NSString *)latitude andLon:(NSString *)longitude andRadius:(NSString *)radius andMeasure:(NSString *)measure {

    NSString *link = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"http://some.website/file.php?lat=%@&lon=%@&ms=%@&dist=%@", latitude, longitude, measure, radius];

    NSData *myData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[link stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]]]];

    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

}

@end
```

ListEvents.swift

```
func getEvents() {
    let getEventsObj:getEvents = getEvents()
    // error: Cannot convert value of type '()' to specified type 'getEvents'

    let jsonString = getEventsObj.objGetEvents(latitude, andLon: longitude, andRadius: searchRadius, andMeasure: searchMeasure) as NSString 
    // error: Static member 'objGetEvents' cannot be used on instance of type 'getEvents'

    print(jsonString)
}
```

PS. I am importing "getEvents.h" in Extension-Bridging-Header.h

---

I am trying to use Objective-C NSData because NSData on Swift and get the contents of my URL as specified in this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40194517/nsdatacontentsof-options-works-on-the-simulator-but-not-on-the-device

Comment: Why is your ObjC class and Swift function have same name? And why class name starts with lowercase?

Comment: First thing to try is rename `getEvents` to `GetEvents`. It is recommended that type start with a capital letter. I'm guessing that having a method with the same name as the type is at least part of the problem.

Comment: You cannot subclass NSString, if you want to extend it - use Cathegory. You see NSString is not a class, it's an abstraction that can have a lot of different implementations in runtime.

Comment: Good point user28434! i'm feeling really stupid now! changing the swift function name fixed the first error. any idea about the second one?

Comment: Also, man, you call your function getEvents() as well as getEvents class, so getEvents() is a constructor of getEvents() and function at the same time

Comment: thanks everybody! everything working now

Comment: You are subclassing NSString? Seriously?

Comment: There are no prizes for the shortest name. Change "Lon" to "Longitude".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared a `class` function, no need for an instance to be created.

Your code should be like:

```
 func getEvents() {
        let jsonString = getEvents.objGetEvents(latitude, andLon: longitude, andRadius: searchRadius, andMeasure: searchMeasure) as NSString 

        print(jsonString)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, after changing my Swift function name and changing my code as you suggested everything is working :)